# The difference between @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth and ms-rest-azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I saw many same method in these two packages, when I use ms-rest-azure(loginWithServicePrincipalSecret) to create a credential and use the credential to instance a SubscriptionClient, it got an error:

[image]

```
Argument of type 'ApplicationTokenCredentials' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ServiceClientCredentials'.
  Types of property 'signRequest' are incompatible.
    Type '(webResource: WebResource, callback: (err: Error) => void) => void' is not assignable to type '(webResource: WebResource) => Promise<WebResource>'.ts(2345)
```

But when I changed to @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth and create credential with loginWithServicePrincipalSecret and use the credential to instance a SubscriptionClient,  it works well.

So I want to know why and the difference between @azure/ms-rest-nodeauth and ms-rest-azure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ms-rest-azure` is the base module for the Node SDK for Azure. `@azure/ms-rest-nodeauth` is a related package specifically for handling authentication. It does look like there recently some issues with mismatched type changes between versions: https://github.com/Azure/ms-rest-nodeauth/issues/67

It's good to hear you were able to resolve the issue. I would encourage you to raise an issue on the [product Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js) so that it can be fixed for other developers. Be sure to include which package versions you are using so they know where to look for the problem.